# Square-To what should $x$ be equal?

Tags: geometry

[image]

At the side $AD=a$ of the square $ABCD$, we take the point $E$ and at the extension of $AB$ the point $Z$, such that $DE=BZ=x$.

a) Show that the line bisector of $EZ$ goes through the vertex $C$.

b) To what should $x$ be equal, so that the line bisector goes through the midpoint of $AB$?

c) To what should $x$ be equal, so that $(CAM)=(EAZ)$?

$$$$

**My attempt:**

c) $(EAZ)=\frac{1}{2}(a+x)(a-x)=\frac{1}{2}(a^2-x^2)$

From the Pythagorean Theorem: $(AD)^2+(DC)^2=(AC)^2 \Rightarrow (AC)^2=2a^2 \Rightarrow (AC)=a \sqrt{2}$

$(CAM)=\frac{1}{2}a \sqrt{2} \cdot (\text{ height })$

Which is the height of this triangle?

a) Do I have to show that $(EC)=(CZ)$? Or do I have to show that $(CM)$ is perpendicular to $(EZ)$?

I have no attempt for b).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is angle CMZ=90 ?

Comment: since the CM is line bisector of EZ,I suppose it is. What do you think?

Comment: not necessary, any line's midpoint can be connected to point C and the connecting line may not make 90 degree angle with that line, also on line EZ any point can be connected to C which may not make 90 degree

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes, showing that EC=CZ would do the job.

b) If the bisector goes through the midpoint of AB (call it K) then the gradient of KC is $a/(a/2)=2$. The gradient of EZ is $(x-a)/(a+x)$. Perpendicular gradients $m_1$ and $m_2$ satisfy $m_1m_2=-1$ so this allows you to find $x$.

c) Note that the length of EAZ is $2a$ irrespective of $x$. So you just need to find the $x$ that gives CAM=$2a$.

Comment: a) from the Pythagorean theorem we have $x^2+a^2=(EC)^2 \Rightarrow (EC)=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$. How can I calculate $(CZ)$? c) how did you find that the length is 2a? Shouldn`t the two areas be equal? Why do we use the length?

Comment: @user159870 In the exact same way. CB=a and BZ=x, so CZ=$\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$ which is the same as EC, therefore they're the same length.

Comment: OK! I see. So the question a) is done! I edited my comment about the question c). Could have a look at?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that EAZ and CAM mean the *area* of the triangles. Are you certain about this? I would interpret them to mean the lengths EAZ=EA+AZ and CAM=CA+AM.

Comment: I thought that since it is enclosed into parentheses, it means areas.

Comment: @user159870 The gradient of KC=2. The gradient of EZ=$(x-a)/(a+x)$. Since they are perpendicular then $2(x-a)/(a+x)=-1$. So rearrange this to solve for $x$.

Comment: OK. Is there a formula to calculate the value of the gradient of a line segment? If we knew the that K(m,n) and C(g,h) it would be $\frac{h-n}{g-m}$, or nor? How did you find this without knowing the exact points?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15750/discussion-between-user159870-and-user2584283).

Comment: How can I find the area of the triangle $CAM$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $AD = DC=CB=BA=a$ and $DE =BZ=x$.

a) 
At first note that the triangles $\triangle CDE$ and $ \triangle CBZ$ are congruent.

Hence we can conclude that $CE = CZ$.

As $EM =MZ$ and $CE=CZ$ it follows that $CM$ is the perpendicular bisector of segment $EZ$.

b)
Let $K$ the intersection point between the lines $CM$ and $AB$.

The triangles $\triangle EAZ$ and $\triangle KBC$ are similar.

Recalling that $K$ is also the midpoint of segment $AB$ we get:
$$\frac{a-x}{a+x}=\frac{\frac{a}{2}}{a}.$$
Therefore
$$x=\frac{a}{3}.$$

c)
Note that$(AMC)=(AMCD)-(ADC)$.

But $(AMCD)=2(AMD)$(Can you prove that $AM =MC$?).

Hence
$$(CAM)=2\frac{a(a+x)}{2}-\frac{a^2}{2}$$
$$ \Rightarrow (CAM)=\frac{a x}{2} \quad (1) $$
The area of $\triangle EAZ$ can be calculated by:
$$(EAZ)= \frac{(a-x)(a+x)}{2} \quad(2) $$
As equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ must be equal, we get:
$$x^2+ax-a^2=0 \quad(3)$$
Solving $(3)$ we get:
$$x= \frac{a(\sqrt{5}-1)}{2}$$